# Multithreaded legacy Java application's threads taking turns in order

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-6

TL;DR - A user has an error (ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allows for this column). I can't recreate it locally because when my machine runs the multithreaded app, only one of ten threads runs at a time, in sequence. Furthermore, running it often results in my machine running out of heap even with 8GB allocated to the heap, and then I happen to hit a NullPointerException instead of the user's issue.

---

I'm attempting to debug a multithreaded legacy Java app (JDK 1.6) written years ago by people that are no longer around. It is attempting to insert some data into an Oracle DB. The app usually runs on a Weblogic 11G server and takes about 5 minutes to finish running the calculations. However, debugging locally, the threads don't work concurrently, they're taking turns on my local machine. This makes the running time go from the aforementioned 5 minutes to ~1 hour and still manages to run out of heap (I gave it 8GB) or throw a NullPointerException if I'm lucky, but that isn't the business user's error. I've thought about cutting it down to use only one thread since it's taking turns anyway, but after touching this for a week, the business impact is becoming real and I can't just keep hitting it with a hammer.

This may be a long shot given I haven't provided and of the code, but does anyone have experience with a similar issue? Specifically why the threads are taking turns.

---

EDIT: the user's error is a constraint violation, so I think it's modifying the inputted data and doing something like adding extra precision.

The problem: The application's 10 threads are working in sequence rather than concurrently and the code potentially contains a memory leak, resulting in the app crashing and not hitting the same code the constraint violation exception that the business user is encountering.

Edit 2: I suspect the threads trading off, rather than running concurrently, could be causing them not to run garbage collection on my local machine perhaps? Though, it still doesn't explain the issue of me receiving a different error than the business user if I'm lucky enough not to run out of heap.

Comment: I'm not a database person so, unlikely to answer, but maybe you could say more about the difference between "on a...server" and "locally." Especially, how does the application connect to the database in either case?

Comment: Also, besides the possible difference in connectivity, how does "attempting to debug" differ from how the application is normally run?

Comment: @SolomonSlow I modified the question because I realized I didn't state the user's issue. Please see the edit. The issue isn't the DB connection though because it successfully commits many rows before it hits the constraint violation.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Both my local machine and the WebLogic server have a valid connection to the Oracle DB. Attempting to debug for me is different in the sense that the server seems to run the threads concurrently, whereas on my machine, they run in sequence, taking turns.

Comment: What JVM(s) are you using?  Are they the same on both server and your machine?  What arguments are passed to the JVM(s)?  Are they the same?  How much logging does this application do?  A well-implemented application like this would have the ability to set logging level to the point where it would tell you what it's doing.  (To all you managers and tech leads reading this:  this week of business impact is on you for not enforcing the implementation of proper logging in a business-critical application. How much time gets spent over the years of an application's life fixing things like this?)

Comment: If you are debugging when running locally and have a breakpoint somewhere in the code being executed by the threads, does this explain the difference you are seeing running locally to running on the server?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Both  are running java 6 (1.6.0 revision 35). I tried to clone the server arguments to match the config to run on my local machine, but some arguments are for other deployments running on the same container. Someone wrote some logging for it about 11 years ago but even at the finest level, because it isn't persisted by something like kodo, there isn't much on the logs other than the manual logging statements the original developer wrote. The logging was really what upset me too. In my opinion, they should have used a solid persistence manager like our other apps.

Comment: @KevinHooke Running locally, it doesn't seem like any of the threads manage to hit the breakpoint where the user's error is being thrown from. Instead, it hits a NullPointerException somewhere before.

Comment: Are you able to run with the same data inputs or against the same db when running locally vs running on the server? If you're getting a NullPointerException when running locally but not on the server, then something is different. Are you able to work out what's different, or confirm you can run locally with the same data to reproduce the original issue?

Comment: OK, since it's a constraint violation I assume you can get the SQL submitted to the DB somehow?  And, you've been trying to identify the problem so you can fix it for a week. What are the odds that spending another week - or two, or three... - is going to identify the problem so you can fix it? Talk to your manager and decide how much longer you're going to bang your head against this wall before trying something else.  After a week, it's time to seriously consider spending the time to put the logging in place that should have been there from the start - spend 2-3 days doing that.

Comment: @KevinHooke I run the same thing locally and on the server. Something is definitely different, but I don't know if the NullPointer is caused by the memory issue or what exactly... I put a breakpoint on the NullPointer code a minute ago, waiting now to see what I see and determine if it's related to the user's issue but I'm pretty sure it won't be, so it's likely a secondary barrier to finding a solution.

Comment: Running the same code is not the same as running with the same data. If you're running the same code locally but seeing different results (the NullPointerException) then you should work out what that difference is if it's blocking you from reproducing the other/main issue. Running out of memory is not going to cause a NullPointerException.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, the SQL is being submitted. I had this discussion with my manager and the rest of the team regarding the timeframe. this is an activity that is supposed to be done every week, and is vital for monthly processes to be complete by the second week of the month. so I suppose I only have another week or so. Unfortunately, I'm the only person in the company that has the time and know-how to  touch this so I don't have any other avenues for support. I think you're on point with the logging though. this could've been avoided with proper logging so  it may be time to make that change.

Comment: @KevinHooke I'm running the same data and it should be the same code, but it was built and deployed 11 years ago and I'm not allowed access to the server to pull the WAR or the EAR to hash it against my own build in the event that my code could be different (but newer certainly) and if hashing it would even yield the same value if they were the same code given the other things that could change the way it's built from machine to machine. Are you sure it's not possible to run out of memory when attempting to allocate space for some given variable during runtime?

Comment: If the code is continually creating new instances of objects and they never go out of scope or are not dereferenced then yes you'll run out of heap but that manifests as an OutOfMemoryError and not a NullPointerException. If you are seeing a NullPointerException it's because you have a reference that is null, that doesn't mean you have run out of memory. These are very different and unrelated issues.

Comment: thank you for the clarification @KevinHooke.  I'll look into the NullPointerException. Hopefully, I can resolve it soon and most likely implement further logging.

Comment: your best bet is to run the code under a profiler like yourkit java profiler (my personal favorite).  that will show you things like thread contention and memory usage.

Comment: @jtahlborn Thank you, I should have thought about using a profiler the first time I noticed it was running out of heap.

Answer (score 2):

You may well be correct in your instincts which tell you that the "threads" are working against you and that your predecessor simply left you with an unworkable design which he could never manage to fix.

*"The eventual recipient,"* in all cases, "is the [Oracle ...] database."  No matter what the application does in presenting requests to it, the only thing that matters is the requests that it receives.  Obviously the clients are colliding with themselves, and it is therefore probable that there's no reason for having multiple threads at all.

Comment: I think my local environment is causing the multithreading to fail in terms of working concurrently since the server manages to spit out the results in 5 minutes; sure, the server has more processing power, but I don't think it could run this whole process in 10 threads that aren't working in sync like mine is doing. I think my predecessor made it multithreaded because it crunches a lot of numbers and it would make sense to split that up across 10 different threads since it's working on thousands of data sets. I'm certain that I need to solve the async issue first.

Comment: @DarrelHolt If the application does have a race condition in it causing it to fail on the production server, and it only runs single-threaded on your system when you're debugging it, you are ***never*** going to solve the problem on your system because it will never manifest itself on your system.  And even if you do get it running multithreaded on your system, given the differences you've implied between the systems, there's still a good chance you'll never be able to duplicate the issue on your system.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The user is getting a constraint violation back from the DB: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allows for this column. I'm pretty sure it's doing a calculation on the raw data it's pulling in and doing something first. My hunch is that it usually does calculations with precision too high for the DB but gets automatically truncated to remove the trailing 0's. But this time the raw data is different somehow. maybe it's not able to remove them because that level of precision used yielded actual values that weren't as precise as before and the dev didn't anticipate that

Comment: @DarrelHolt And I strongly suspect it's safe to assume you're not getting that same output on your system when you feed the application the exact same same input data on your development system?  And you can see the SQL the application generates in production that blows up?  Which means you somehow have to figure out why the application does that?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I can't get the same output because my machine runs out of heap and takes too long to get to the point the user is having an error due to my machine using one thread at a time. I can see the raw SQL statement, but I can't see the values it's using. I'm pretty sure it's hibernate, but I don't see anything on the console/logs like I'd expect. Otherwise, I'd just trace it back to that. So ya, I have to fix the multithreading, the nullPointer, and real issue or just fix the nullPointer, get lucky to not leak all of my memory, and manage to hit the query that is throwing the exception

Comment: If the production server doesn't run out of heap, why does your system?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I suspect it has something to do with the way the threads are acting. Maybe each thread's execution is exiting without freeing the memory it's using, then the next thread starts its part, does the same, rinse and repeat until we get back to the first and it goes to the next entry from the data set it's supposed to process. The production servers are a lot larger though so let's say they have 16G dedicated to this app and it can successfully finish the process, remove the request from the queue, and the dev manually deallocated the giant hashmap or whatever he was using at the end.